ROS2 humble rosidl \${_header_name}__type_support.hpp doesn't generated, but ${_header_name}.hpp use it
I met a compile error:
/home/nuc/catkin_ws/ros2/src_moveit/install/ocs2_msgs/include/ocs2_msgs/ocs2_msgs/msg/mode_schedule.hpp:10:10: fatal error: ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/mode_schedule__type_support.hpp: No such file or directory
   10 | #include "ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/mode_schedule__type_support.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



1. constraint.hpp need constraint__type_support.hpp
uc@nuc:~/catkin_ws/ros2/src_moveit/install/ocs2_msgs/include/ocs2_msgs/ocs2_msgs/msg$ cat constraint.hpp
// generated from rosidl_generator_cpp/resource/idl.hpp.em
// generated code does not contain a copyright notice

#ifndef OCS2_MSGS__MSG__CONSTRAINT_HPP_
#define OCS2_MSGS__MSG__CONSTRAINT_HPP_

#include "ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/constraint__struct.hpp"
#include "ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/constraint__builder.hpp"
#include "ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/constraint__traits.hpp"
#include "ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/constraint__type_support.hpp"

#endif  // OCS2_MSGS__MSG__CONSTRAINT_HPP_

2. but constraint__type_support.hpp doesn't created
3. detail/constraint__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.hpp is created by rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp_generate_interfaces.cmake

4. but constraint.hpp don't use it.

constraint__type_support.h is there
constraint__type_support.cpp also there, constraint__type_support.cpp include the constraint__type_support.h not constraint__type_support.hpp

is there any config I haven't set to cause this problem?

I use this way as a workaround:
#include <ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/constraint__struct.hpp>
#include <ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/constraint__builder.hpp>
#include <ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/constraint__traits.hpp>
#include <ocs2_msgs/msg/detail/constraint__type_support.h>

// #include <ocs2_msgs/msg/constraint.hpp>

but it seems the IDL has a bug, a proper solution may as following.
diff --git a/rosidl_generator_cpp/cmake/rosidl_generator_cpp_generate_interfaces.cmake b/rosidl_generator_cpp/cmake/rosidl_generator_cpp_generate_interfaces.cmake
index 0240e5b..57bc6e3 100644
--- a/rosidl_generator_cpp/cmake/rosidl_generator_cpp_generate_interfaces.cmake
+++ b/rosidl_generator_cpp/cmake/rosidl_generator_cpp_generate_interfaces.cmake
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@ foreach(_abs_idl_file ${rosidl_generate_interfaces_ABS_IDL_FILES})
     "${_output_path}/${_parent_folder}/detail/${_header_name}__builder.hpp"
     "${_output_path}/${_parent_folder}/detail/${_header_name}__struct.hpp"
     "${_output_path}/${_parent_folder}/detail/${_header_name}__traits.hpp"
-    "${_output_path}/${_parent_folder}/detail/${_header_name}__type_support.hpp"
+    "${_output_path}/${_parent_folder}/detail/${_header_name}__type_support.h"
   )
 endforeach()

